# Verify that connection to Cygwin SFTP Server is encrypted

Tags: windows, ssh, encryption, cygwin, sftp

I must ensure that my flow is encrypted. I am on a Windows machine and I have installed a SFTP server via Cygwin.. I am using WinSCP as client. And I am developing another client in C#. Everything works correctly but I am not sure that encryption is enabled.

In my `sshd_config` I don't have any list of ciphers as reported [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) (under `Ciphers`).

In my `/etc/sshd_config` file I have this

```
#Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none
```

Just this.. I don't have any cipher... This is the first reason why I think that encryption is not enabled.

Another reason is that in the client I am developing I see a property:

```
CurrentServerEncryption = NULL
```

So it looks like I don't have any encryption.

Can anyone tell my please how to edit my `sshd_config` to enable ciphers or how can I check if ciphers are enabled?

Comment: Use WireShark.  This will allow you to verify the traffic is encrypted.

Comment: I have to transfer a file... I do not know wireshark.. How can I understand if is encrypted? Do you have a link for a guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The block in the `sshd_config`, you refer to, is all commented-out (the starting `#`). So the defaults apply. The default for the `Ciphers` does not include the `none` cipher, so the server does not allow unencrypted connections. Note that the standard build of OpenSSH does not even allow you to enable the `none` encryption. You would have to recompile OpenSSH.
  See [How can I disable encryption on openssh?](https://serverfault.com/q/116875/168875)
- WinSCP does not allow the `none` cipher either.
  See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_ssh
  So if you can connect with WinSCP, the connection is encrypted.
- In WinSCP log, you can see the negotiated cipher:

  ```
    . 2014-11-06 16:41:26.328 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
    . 2014-11-06 16:41:26.328 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
    . 2014-11-06 16:41:26.328 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
    . 2014-11-06 16:41:26.328 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
  ```
- Regarding the `CurrentServerEncryption`: I assume you refer to [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) `Session.ConnectionInfo.CurrentServerEncryption`, right?
  Are you reading the value AFTER you have connected to the server? Also note that even, if the connection is unencrypted, the value should read `"none"`, not `NULL`. The `NULL` likely indicates the cipher has not been selected yet (connection is not opened).